# How to add a line to a multiline TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

How can i add a line of text to a [multi-line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.multiline%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)?

e.g. pseudocode;

```
textBox1.Clear();
textBox1.Lines.Add("1000+");
textBox1.Lines.Add("750-999");
textBox1.Lines.Add("400-749");
...snip...
textBox1.Lines.Add("40-59");
```

or

```
textBox1.Lines.Append("brown");
textBox1.Lines.Append("brwn");
textBox1.Lines.Append("brn");
textBox1.Lines.Append("brow");
textBox1.Lines.Append("br");
textBox1.Lines.Append("brw");
textBox1.Lines.Append("brwm");
textBox1.Lines.Append("bron");
textBox1.Lines.Append("bwn");
textBox1.Lines.Append("brnw");
textBox1.Lines.Append("bren");
textBox1.Lines.Append("broe");
textBox1.Lines.Append("bewn");
```

The only methods that [TextBox.Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) implements (that i can see) are:

- Clone
- CopyTo
- Equals
- GetType
- GetHashCode
- GetEnumerator
- Initialize
- GetLowerBound
- GetUpperBound
- GetLength
- GetLongLength
- GetValue
- SetValue
- ToString

[image]

Comment: can't you use append(Enviroment.NewLine)  ??

Comment: TextBox.Lines is a read only representation of the text.  Please refere to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx.

Comment: @Casperah Ohhh, that helps to explain why it can't be used to do what i want - Microsoft is (in a not-so-subtle-way) preventing you from doing a slower code path

Comment: Casperah - The documentation link you sent plainly states: "Gets or sets the lines of text in a text box control."  Gets or SETS. The issue is not that it isn't changeable, but _how_ it is to be changed. Lines is a pointer (reference) to an array, so you have to build an array of strings then point Lines to it. string [] newLines = string [5]; textbox.Lines = newLines;

Answer (score 121, accepted):

@Casperah pointed out that i'm thinking about it wrong:

- A `TextBox` doesn't *have* lines
- it has **text**
- that text can be split on the CRLF into lines, if requested
- but there is no notion of **lines**

The question then is how to accomplish what i want, rather than what WinForms lets me.

There are subtle bugs in the other given variants:

- `textBox1.AppendText("Hello" + Environment.NewLine);`
- `textBox1.AppendText("Hello" + "\r\n");`
- `textBox1.Text += "Hello\r\n"`
- `textbox1.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + "brown";`

They either append or prepend a newline when one (might) not be required.

So, extension helper:

```
public static class WinFormsExtensions
{
   public static void AppendLine(this TextBox source, string value)
   {
      if (source.Text.Length==0)
         source.Text = value;
      else
         source.AppendText("\r\n"+value);
   }
}
```

So now:

```
textBox1.Clear();
textBox1.AppendLine("red");
textBox1.AppendLine("green");
textBox1.AppendLine("blue");
```

and

```
textBox1.AppendLine(String.Format("Processing file {0}", filename));
```

**Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.

Answer (score 27):

I would go with the `System.Environment.NewLine` or a `StringBuilder`

Then you could add lines with a string builder like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("brown");
sb.AppendLine("brwn");

textbox1.Text += sb.ToString();
```

or NewLine like this:

```
textbox1.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + "brown";
```

Better:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(textbox1.Text);
sb.AppendLine("brown");
sb.AppendLine("brwn");

textbox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Good answer, but constructor name is same as class name - StringBuilder (d missing) :)

Answer (score 17):

Append a `\r\n` to the string to put the text on a new line.

```
textBox1.Text += ("brown\r\n");
textBox1.Text += ("brwn");
```

This will produce the two entries on separate lines.

Comment: It won't work, `TextBox` control will not handle the `\n` properly, you must use `\r\n` for that, please check yourself

Comment: Or `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
textBox1.Text += "SomeText\r\n"
```

you can also try

```
textBox1.Text += "SomeText" + Environment.NewLine;
```

Where `\r` is carriage return and `\n` is new line

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the `AppendText` method of the textbox directly. If you try to use the `Text` property, the textbox will not scroll down as new line are appended.

```
textBox1.AppendText("Hello" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 4):

The "Lines" property of a TextBox is an array of strings. By definition, you cannot add elements to an existing `string[]`, like you can to a `List<string>`. There is simply no method available for the purpose. You must instead create a new `string[]` based on the current Lines reference, and assign it to Lines.

Using a little Linq (.NET 3.5 or later):

```
textBox1.Lines = textBox.Lines.Concat(new[]{"Some Text"}).ToArray();
```

This code is fine for adding one new line at a time based on user interaction, but for initializing a textbox with a few dozen new lines, it will perform very poorly. If you're setting the initial value of a TextBox, I would either set the Text property directly using a StringBuilder (as other answers have mentioned), or if you're set on manipulating the Lines property, use a List to compile the collection of values and then convert it to an array to assign to Lines:

```
var myLines = new List<string>();

myLines.Add("brown");
myLines.Add("brwn");
myLines.Add("brn");
myLines.Add("brow");
myLines.Add("br");
myLines.Add("brw");
...

textBox1.Lines = myLines.ToArray();
```

Even then, because the Lines array is a calculated property, this involves a lot of unnecessary conversion behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

The adding of `Environment.NewLine` or `\r\n` was not working for me, initially, with my textbox.  I found I had forgotten to go into the textbox's **Behavior** properties and set the "**Multiline**" property to "**True**" for it to add the lines!  I just thought I'd add this caveat since no one else did in the answers, above, and I had thought the box was just going to auto-expand and forgot I needed to actually set the Mulitline property for it to work.  I know it's sort of a bonehead thing (which is the kind of thing that happens to us late on a Friday afternoon), but it might help someone remember to check that.  Also, in the Appearance section is the "ScrollBars" property that I needed to set to "Both", to get both horizontal and vertical bars so that text could actually be scrolled and seen in its entirety.  So the answer here isn't just a code one by appending `Environment.NewLine` or `\r\n` to the `.Text`, but also make sure your box is set up properly with the right properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a line break into your text.

You don't add lines as a method. Multiline just supports the use of line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many lines you want, create an array of String with that many members (e.g. myStringArray).
Then use myListBox.Lines = myStringArray;

Answer (score 0):

Above methods did not work for me. I got the following exception:

```
Exception : 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

Turns out I needed to call `Invoke` on my controls first. See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38065472/6329629).