# Double line break added when appending string to textBox in WinForm

Tags: c#, arrays, string, winforms

I have the two following code pieces:

```
    private void AddTextToLog(string textToAdd)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(@"Raw Text: " + textToAdd);
        textToAdd = RemoveInvalidCharacters(textToAdd);
        var array = ParseLogText(textToAdd);
        foreach (var entry in array)
        {
            _log.Add(entry);
            MainForm.Get.UISynchContext.Send(o => MainForm.Get.AddToChatLog(entry), null);
        }
    }
```

And:

```
    public void AddToChatLog(string text)
    {
        tbChatLog.AppendText("\r\n" + text);
        //tbChatLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

    }
```

What happens here is that when `AddTextLog(text)` is called, some new text is appended to tbChatLog, which is a textBox.

The weird thing is that, if in do not include `\r\n` or `Environment.NewLine` in `AddToChatLog` method, then all gets added directly after each other, without any line breaks or whitespace. If I add one of those two line break codes, then not only is it dropped to the next line of the textbox, but a whole empty line is added too. So it seems it does two line breaks.

Any idea?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

This is the text without any line-break added:

```
A710E000A:Simon:1A7110000A:Simon:2A7118000A:Simon:3
```

If I add a line break of some sort to `AddToChatLog`, I get this:

```
A721F000A:Simon:1

A7222000A:Simon:2

A7223000A:Simon:3
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Hmmmm, I added a `Console.WriteLine("ENTRY: " + entry)` to the `AddTextToLog` method, and turns out every time it adds something in the for loop, there is also an empty entry. That is really bizarre. I got the array from a string.Split method, there should be no empty entries in the array...

---

**SOLUTION:**

I was Split'ing on a certain set of characters, which as it turns out the master-string could start with. If you split at the start of a string you actually get a string array with one empty string at top. Two fixes that both work: One was stripping empty array entries with Linq. The other, which is easier, is just to create a Substring from the master string, that starts a few characters in, so split does not happen at the start of the master-string.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You're telling it to add a carriage return and a newline `\r\n`, which is why you get a 'double line break'.

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` does the same thing though

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` returns `\r\n` on windows...

Comment: What should I use instead? I tried just `\n` and just `\r`, but that did not work. It actually made the program crash, for some reason...

Comment: Have you tried to check the contents of the TextBox after the `AppendText` call? Is it `previous \r\n current` or is it something else? What are the contents if you manually make a line break from the keyboard? Have you tried to append only the linebreak?

Comment: It may be the case of adding breaks when not having any text yet. Have a look at the extension method in the accepted answer of a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536958/how-to-add-a-line-to-a-multiline-textbox

Comment: @musicfuel Just tried the extension method, it did not work for me unfortunately.

Comment: @Anders Can you try to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Because `NewLine ` works perfectly on a clean project. Maybe the issue is caused by `UISynchContext` use or by something else.

Comment: What does a typical `textToAdd` string look like and what does the body of `ParseLogText` do?

Comment: The comments helped me think outside of the box, resulting in me figuring out what was wrong. I was Split'ing on a certain set of characters that the master-string could start with. If you split at the first character you actually get a string array with one empty string at the beginning. So I made two fixes, one was stripping empty array entries with Linq. The other which is easier is just to create a substring from the master string, that starts a few characters in, so split does not happen at the start of the master-string.