# TCP/IP Client _Server Connection

Tags: c#, tcp, listbox

I have a listBox with numbers. I would like to sent the values from the listBox (on client- side)  to another listbox  (on server- side). The code works especially well with textBox1.Text (see below). I would like to have the numbers ( listbox on Server-Side) among each other(see figure). How can this be solved? 
Many thanks for your help and support!

```
//Client:

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
           client.WriteLineAndGetReply(textBox1.Text,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));                           
        }

//Server:

        private void Server_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {   
                textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                {
                    textBox1.Text += e.MessageString;
                    e.ReplyLine(string.Format(e.MessageString));
                });            
        }
```

[image]

Comment: _"I would like to have the numbers ( listbox on Server-Side) among each other."_ Could you post an example of what this means?

Comment: So, that's what you _have_. And in contrast to that (or additionally) what is your goal? I'm having a hard time understanding your question, because it is unclear what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I have a textBox with numbers" : [ 1,2,3 ]  on client side. I have also a textBox on server side. The output after sending: [1,2,3].  I would like to have something like that: listboxes with numbers on client side and on server side among each other  :                                   [1
2
3]                                                                                                                             
I hope it has become clear what the diffrence is...

Comment: Ohhh, ... each number on its own line ... d'oh. Now I get it.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8537564/982149 I guess it will help.

Comment: It is possible to sent data like this:        client.WriteLineAndGetReply(listBox25.Items...(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)); 
However, thank you very much for all your efforts, Fildor!