# how do i print the contents of a gridview to a textbox

Tags: c#

I want to output the contents of my `GridView` to a `TextBox` and each row gets its own line. This is what I have right now but it only outputs the first row into the **TextBox**

```
for (int i = 0; i < POSDGV.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    string Item = POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    string Amount = POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    string Receipt = Item + " " + Amount;
    Receipttxt.Text = Receipt + "\n";
}
```

Thx for the help

Comment: can you try `i++`

Comment: still doesn't work, i++ and ++i are the same thing

Comment: you need to do `Receipttxt.Text += Receipt + "\n";`

Comment: `i++ and ++i are the same thing`...that depends on the context.

Comment: Normally a textbox in a webpage is not multiline by default. Did you set yours to be multiline with `TextMode="MultiLine"` in the markup? (I'm assuming you're talking about ASP.NET Webforms here, because of the mention of GridView. But if you actually mean WinForms and DataGridView, it might be different. You really need to clarify - there are tags you can add to your post for the relevant technologies).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a line to a multiline TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536958/how-to-add-a-line-to-a-multiline-textbox)

Comment: I found the issue apparenlty it works when i do ```Environment.Newline``` but not ```/n```

Comment: That's because in Windows a newline is triggered by `\r\n` (carriage return + line feed) not just `\n` (line feed). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation shows you the newline characters required in various operating systems. `Environment.NewLine` is a constant provided by .NET so that you don't need to know this for yourself and can just let the framework handle it depending on the O/S it's running on.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the technology, but for Windows.Forms there is the `Multiline` attribute that you can use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.multiline?view=netcore-3.1

Check this answer here [How to add a line to a multiline TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536958/how-to-add-a-line-to-a-multiline-textbox) for an example. Notable mention the eventing method:

```
public static class WinFormsExtensions
{
   public static void AppendLine(this TextBox source, string value)
   {
      if (source.Text.Length==0)
         source.Text = value;
      else
         source.AppendText("\r\n"+value);
   }
}
```