# How do I print multiple lines on a label in win forms

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, winforms, permutation

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int n;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            string scrambledWord = textBox1.Text;

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                label3.Text   = scrambledWord;
                int n = scrambledWord.Length;
                permute(scrambledWord, 0, n - 1);
            }
              

        }
        private void permute(String scrambledWord,
                            int l, int r)
        {
            if (l == r)
                label3.Text = scrambledWord;
            else
            {
                for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
                {
                    scrambledWord = swap(scrambledWord, l, i);
                    permute(scrambledWord, l + 1, r);
                    scrambledWord = swap(scrambledWord, l, i);
                }
            }
        }

        /** 
        * Swap Characters at position 
        * @param a string value 
        * @param i position 1 
        * @param j position 2 
        * @return swapped string 
        */
        public static String swap(String a,
                                  int i, int j)
        {
            char temp;
            char[] charArray = a.ToCharArray();
            temp = charArray[i];
            charArray[i] = charArray[j];
            charArray[j] = temp;
            string s = new string(charArray);
            return s;
        }

    }
}
```

It is only printing the first line of the permutation, I would like it to print all the permutations. I am new to WinForms. Pls help, Thank you! ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

Comment: Multiple Line? Use a text box. and set the property multiline to true. something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536958/how-to-add-a-line-to-a-multiline-textbox

Comment: Youe Label will display multiple lines just fine and is a much simpler control than a TextBox. You need to insert line break and/or new line character, if course. It will not wrap around by itself; and user will be able to copy from the Label.

Comment: @TaW how do i do that?

Comment: Really? How do you insert a character or string into a string you are building up? Add `"\n"` or `"\r"` or `"\r\n"` before adding the data for the next line..!

Comment: @TaW I tried that it didn't work. Thank you though. Sorry for being a noob I am 14 and new to C#

Comment: That's fine; it should work but without seeing the new code we can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code to use Environment.Newline() to show all the permutations in the label.

First, we need to set the label.AutoSize to be false.

Second, here is a code example you can refer to.

```
 private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            string scrambledWord = textBox1.Text;

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                label1.Text ="";
                char[] arr = scrambledWord.ToCharArray();
                GetPer(arr);
            }
        }

        public  void GetPer(char[] list)
        {
            int x = list.Length - 1;
            GetPer(list, 0, x);
        }

        private  void GetPer(char[] list, int k, int m)
        {
            if (k == m)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list);
                var text = new string(list);
                label1.Text = label1.Text + text + Environment.NewLine;
           
            }
            else
                for (int i = k; i <= m; i++)
                {
                    Swap(ref list[k], ref list[i]);
                    GetPer(list, k + 1, m);
                    Swap(ref list[k], ref list[i]);
                }
        }
        private  void Swap(ref char a, ref char b)
        {
            if (a == b) return;

            var temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }

        private void label1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Height = label1.Height + 10;
        }
```

Result:

[image]